# No wallpaper after installing Gnome Shell [13.04]

Tags: unity, gnome, nautilus, desktop-background, dconf

After installing Gnome Shell 3.8, my wallpaper disapear and I see only white space on desktop. After `nautilus -q` white turn into black, but I still can't see picture (Picture is set correctly, because I see it on login screen).
 Problem is in Unity as well as in Gnome Shell.

Every key in dconf (org/gnome/nautilus/desktop) is set to default.